# receive returned value by class in oop

Tags: php, oop

i have a class like this :

```
<?php
class connection {
    public $db;

    public function __construct() { 
    $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', '');

    if($this->db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('error ' . $this->db->connect_error);
    }
    $this->db->set_charset("utf8");
    }

}

class masssave extends connection {
    public $sql;
    public function insert_all {
    // do some works
            if ( $sql = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO $db_name ($str_db_value) values ($str_form_value_found) ")) {
            return true;    
            }
            else {
            return false;
            }
    }


}
?>
```

in `masssave` class i seted `$sql` as public , now i want to use this class in some pages , like register page

```
$save = new masssave;
if ( $save->sql = true ) {
    echo 'ok';
} 
else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

but the upper code is not working , it always `echo 'ok'` even the query was failed ,

i also use `if ( $save->sql == true )` but this code always `echo 'failed'`

i am newbie in oop , but i think my php classes are ok , i think i am doing wrong way for checking returned value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. replace `$sql = $this->db->query` with  `$this->sql = $this->db->query` -- `$sql` - local variable. `$this->sql` - object property
2. call proper method after `$save = new masssave;` use `$save->insert_all()`
3. use comparison (but not assigment) `$save->sql = true` - assigment, `$save->sql == true` - comparison. Assigment reutrns value of variable, so `$save->sql = true` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

This line should be...

```
if ( $save->insert_all() == true )
```

Because....First off, you are just checking if $save->sql is set, which will always echo true in your case.

Also you weren't even checking you were actually setting  (= vs ==)

```
$save = new masssave;
if ( $save->sql = true )
```

Should be...

```
$save = new masssave;
if ( $save->sql == true ) {
```

But that will always return true anyways, because its just checking if the variable exists, which it does.  What you really want is what I posted at the top.  Because query is actually inside the insert_all function, which is where you are returning true or false.

Comment: also, it's possible the $sql = will always be true because he's just assigning a variable there

Comment: @KyleK it's not working , please see code again , `insert_all` it's not returning any thing , `$sql` return `true or false`

Comment: Have you set $sql = $this->db->query to $this->sql = $this->db->query...also are you sure your posted query is working even?? maybe for now remove that and just return true, inside the insert_all function and see if if($save->insert_all == true) works

Answer (score 0):

It will always `echo ok` because you're setting the `$save->sql` to `true`

```
if ( $save->sql = true ) {
```

The above is a big **NO NO**.

What you want is to compare it, so using `==` to compare the values

```
if ( $save->sql == true ) {
```

It would be simpler to just do:

```
if($save->sql) {
    echo 'ok;
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

the above `if` check is basically saying `IF(TRUE) { SAY OK} ELSE { SAY FAIL}`

Comment: in this case it's always `echo 'fail'` even it was true